# Awk: How to substitute a string every four lines?

Tags: awk

I have a file, where **every four lines** is like this:

```
  HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283 1:N:0:GTTTCG
```

(for those interested, this file contains DNA sequences)

I need to remove everything after the space, apart from the first digit after the space (in this case `1`), and then insert `/` between the beginning of the string and the digit, so I get this:

```
  HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283/1
```

I only know Perl and this would take forever in it with my files which are >10GB, so I am hoping you can help with your awk knowledge.

Comment: As a beginner I am asking: Are you sure that a Perl script would be so slowly compared to awk/sed? If yes, why?

Comment: Can you give a sample input, what are the line numbers of interest exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="/"} NR%4==1{$2=$2*1}1' file
```

With `NR%4==1` we get all line number which are 4K+1. In those lines we do `{$2=$2*1}`, that is, to convert the 2nd part after the space into just the number. Then with `{}1` we are printing all the lines.
To make the records to be separated by "/" we use the `BEGIN{OFS="/"}` part, as OFS stands for "output field separator".

Note that the condition `NR%4==1` may be changed depending on the position of the string to be changed. If it is the 1st, 5st, 9th... it's ok like this. If it's 2nd, 6th... then `NR%4==2` and so on.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283 1:N:0:GTTTCG 
a
b
d
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283 7:N:0:GTTTCG 
ad
f
d
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283 9:N:0:GTTTCG 
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="/"}NR%4==1{$2=$2*1}5' a
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283/1
a
b
d
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283/7
ad
f
d
HISEQ15:454:D27KKACXX:6:2316:16241:100283/9
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be almost perfect - only that any single digit can come after the space, it does not have to be 1.

Comment: Oh, now I notice @DoubleDecker.  I am checking it, give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: @DoubleDecker check my updated answer. I think now it is done.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and I think it is cleaner:

```
sed 's! \([0-9]\).*!/\1!;n;n;n;' input
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR%4==1 { $0=$1"/"substr($2,1,1); }1' input
```

Comment: Thanks but again, 1 after the space was just an example, it can be any single digit which I need to keep, so it could be /2 etc. depending which digit comes up after the space.

Comment: there is no 1 here that is hard coded, it should work with any digit after the space, just try it

Comment: Note that in the `awk` version the output is `...283 1` instead of `...283/1`. In my solution it is solved.

Comment: Fedoroqui is right, we get no slash added somehow. And sed produces exactly the same output as input.

Comment: yep, think it;s because you are interested in lines 1,5,9... whereas my answers are for lines 4, 8, 12... updating though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would take longer for a Perl program to do this, unless you used a [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop to go through the file. ( Which would load the entire file before any processing could occur. ) The main bottleneck is generally going to be IO, no matter what language you are using.

```
$ perl -pe 's( (\d).*){/$1} if $. % 4 == 1' filename
```

Which is (largely) the equivalent of

```
while ( <ARGV> ) {
    s[ (\d).*][/$1] if $. % 4 == 1;
    print $_
}
```

If you need to adjust which line to modify, just change the `1` to whatever it needs to be.
Depending on the data you could just remove the `if $. % 4  == 1` part. ( [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) is the current line number )

```
$ perl -pe 's( (\d).*){/$1}' filename
```

If you want to modify the file in-place just add an [`-i`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-i%2a%5b_extension_%5d) to the command.
You could also give [`-i`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-i%2a%5b_extension_%5d) an argument if you want a backup `-i'.orig'`.

```
$ perl -i -pe 's( (\d).*){/$1}' filename
```

Comment: The Awk vs Perl processing time is irrelevant, as you will be spending almost all your time in I/O wait, anyway. +1